# External display isn't used if lid is closed

Tags: display, high-sierra, sleep-wake, macbook-pro

I want to be able to use a macbook with external display with closed lid, but it cannot do that. As soon as I close the lid, there's no signal to the display and no amount of keystrokes on external keyboard or mouse can change that.

A few things which I tried **(all totally useless):**

- NoSleep
- `caffeinate` running in background
- disabling sleep: `sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1`

Display is connected via HDMI.
Macos version = 10.13.6.
AC adapter is plugged in.

Comment: There's an [issue with DisplayLink](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/548400-cannot-use-clamshell-mode-on-mac-os-x) preventing closed clam-shell mode from working properly in High Sierra.  How are you connecting to HDMI, via an adapter?  Which MBP are you using?

Comment: @Allan directly, and it works while lid is open. MBP late 2013 with 2 GPUs.

Comment: The best way to test this is to install a previous version of macOS (i.e. El Capitan) onto an *external* drive (for testing).  If the problem goes away, it will confirm that the bug is related to High Sierra.

Comment: Have you tried PRAM reset: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204063

Comment: @unknowndomain Do you mean [reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)? SMC controls sleep/wake functions.